# A question on Noetherian $R$ -module.

Tags: ring-theory

Let $M$ be Noetherian $R$-module(where $R$ contains $1$) and $\phi:M \to M$ be $R$ -module homomorphism . Suppose $\phi$ is surjective, how do I show that $\phi$ is injective ?

Hints will suffice, thank you.

Comment: Please attempt to use the search function first. Searching "Noetherian surjective injective " brings you to duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the noetherianity we have $\ker(\phi^n) = \ker(\phi^{n+1})$ for some $n$.

$\phi$ is surjective, so $\phi^n$ is surjective; suppose $v \in \ker(\phi)$, so $\exists \ w $ such that $$ v= \phi^n(w) \Rightarrow 0 = \phi(v) = \phi^{n+1}(w) \Rightarrow w \in \ker(\phi^{n+1})$$ But $\ker(\phi^n) = \ker(\phi^{n+1})$ and so $$v= \phi^n(w) = 0 \Rightarrow \ker(\phi) = 0 $$ Then $\phi$ is injective

Comment: *Hint will suffice*.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\ker \phi\subseteq \ker \phi^2\subseteq \dotsb$ is an ascending chain.

Comment: $\text{ker}(\phi^n)$ is submodule of $M$ and since $M$ is Noetherian, the ascending chain will terminate.

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo Yes; if $\ker\phi\ne\{0\}$, there's $n$ such that $\ker\phi^{n-1}\ne\ker\phi^n=\ker\phi^{n+1}$ (where $\phi^0$ is the identity, of course).

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo The sequence is stationary; but it starts, if $\ker\phi\ne\{0\}$, with $\{0\}=\ker\phi^0\subsetneq\ker\phi^1$, so you just pick the maximum $n$ such that $\ker\phi^{n-1}\subsetneq\ker\phi^n$.

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo Why the minimum? The minimum such would be $1$ and would be useless, because you wouldn't be able to use the stationarity of the chain and the surjectivity of $\phi$.